# Symbolic links messing up gconf2 installation on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: symlink, dpkg, gconf

I had trouble installing default-jre on Ubuntu 14.04 and uninstalled gconf2. Maybe that was stupid. In any case, now I'm getting the following error when trying to re-install gconf2:

```
Setting up gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/gconftool-2 to provide /usr/bin/gconftool (gconftool) in auto mode
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gconf2.postinst: 81: /var/lib/dpkg/info/gconf2.postinst: gconf-schemas: Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gconf2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have no idea how to resolve this, any help would be much appreciated.